# No impact on URL with Material-UI BottomNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to create a Bottom Navigation bar using material-ui (link:https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/).

Unfortunately, when I created the component, clicking on each tap did not affect my URL.

Initially, I was using the Link component from React, which allowed me to route between various components. However, as I integrate the Link component into the BottomNavigation component, the style changes and is not working properly anymore.

Here's my current code (without the Link component):

```js
function NavigationAuth() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("/");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      value={value} 
      onChange={handleChange} 
      showLabels
    >
      <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" value="/" icon={<HomeIcon />} />
      <BottomNavigationAction label="Progress" value="/home" icon={<TimelineIcon />} />
      <BottomNavigationAction label="Vote" value="/overview" icon={<ThumbsUpDownIcon />} />
      <BottomNavigationAction label="Account" value="/account" icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
    </BottomNavigation>
  );
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can actually change the URL (while using the BottomNavigation component) as a normal Link component would do?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import `{useHistory}` from `react-router-dom` and use it to change the URL:

```
function NavigationAuth() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      history.push(`/${newValue}`);
      setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        value={value} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        showLabels
      >
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" value="" icon={<HomeIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Progress" value="progress" icon={<TimelineIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Vote" value="overview" icon={<ThumbsUpDownIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Account" value="account" icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
      </BottomNavigation>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Also check out the explanation by Brian

Comment: It looks like the issue comes with the ${newValue}. Because if I hard code it, I dont have any problems. But if I want to chnage it dynamically, it cuts of the URL to https ://home or https ://overview.

Comment: Is the problem still persisting? If so, check out the code - I edited it. The problem was your value was something like "/overview" so I changed it to be just "overview".

Comment: It worked for me when I deleted the "/" and changed it to: history.push(`${newValue}`);

Answer (score 0):

You need both `react-router` and `material-ui` to accomplish what you're describing. Material-ui is a UI library and has no intention of providing functionality like routing, only the UI to control routing however you see fit.

Instead of using `Link`, and assuming this component is wrapped by `BrowserRouter` at a higher level, change the URL in your `handleChange` function like this:

```js
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  props.history.push(newValue);
};
```

`history` is a prop injected by `react-router` that lets you programmatically update the URL by calling `push`.

The other way to do this would be the [`useHistory` hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) instead of passing it as a prop.